# Почему не виден nvm если запускать через ssh2?

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, nvm

Ос Ubuntu 22.04.

В системе 2 оболочки bash и zsh.
В обоих конфиг файлах оболочек и .profile прописаны команды на запуск nvm.

Сам nvm установлен и настроен.
Если открыть терминал и ввести

```
nvm -v
```

то выведет 0.39.5.
Если переключаться между оболочками, перезагружать систему то nvm всегда загружена в оболочку.

Если подключиться пользователем test по ssh с другого компьютера
ssh test@192.22.10.70

То там все ок, оболочкой будет zsh и там присутствует nvm и node версии 8.17

А вот при запуске **внутри node приложения через пакет ssh2**.
Под тем же пользователем test к тому же ip 192.22.10.70,
он выводит того же пользователя и оболочку которые требуются,
whoami = test
echo $0 = zsh

Но вот
Версия node = 12, а не 8

И Пишет
zsh:1: command not found: nvm

То есть при исполнении команды через ssh2 не загружаются профили zsh или bash где прописаны команды экспорта nvm?

Такое же поведение если подключаться c ключом -T

```
ssh -T test@192.22.10.70
```

---

Пример кода

```
const { Client } = require('ssh2');

const conn = new Client(); // создаем клиент

let command = "cd /home/manking/test/prog1 && nvm -v  2>&1 | tee /home/manking/test/data/releases/logs/dev.txt"; // nvm not found

// Соединяемся 
conn.exec(command, { pty: pty }, (err, stream) => {

          if (err) {
            console.log('conn.exec err=', err);

}).connect({
        host,
        port: 22,
        username: sshUser, // имя пользователя
        privateKey: fs.readFileSync(sshPrivateKey), // ключ ssh
        readyTimeout
      });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но всё-таки на всякий случай покажите как конкретно вы делаете запуск «внутри node приложения через пакет ssh2»

Comment: Приложил пример кода. Только я не пойму это в версии 22.04 поменялось что то в работе ssh или я где то не настроил взаимодействие на сервере? До обновления с 20.10 (переустановка на новый диск) все работало.

Comment: Погодите, когда я прогнал у себя установщик nvm, он записал себя в .bashrc, а вовсе не в .profile. Вы сами внесли изменения в .profile или вы всё-таки что-то напутали или что конкретно вы имеете в виду под «обоих конфиг файлах оболочек»?

Comment: Кроме того, в стандартном `.bashrc` прописана проверка на наличие интерактивной оболочки, а `.zshrc` в принципе запускатся только в интерактивной оболочке. Это вполне объясняет, почему nvm не появляется в НЕинтерактивных оболочках, таких как `ssh -T` и в node+ssh2

Comment: Когда устанавливается nvm он сам выводит код который просит вставить в нужную оболочку. 
Вот я этот код всегда добавлял в .bashrc и .zshrc. Плюс еще добавил в .profile.
Рисунок приложил к вопросу.

Comment: У меня установщик ничего не просил и вставил всё автоматически. Вы показали скриншот .bashrc, который не выполняется в неинтерактивных оболочках, файл .zshrc тоже не выполняется, а файл .profile не выполняется в zsh. В итоге получается, что у вас нет абсолютно ничего, что могло бы подключить nvm

Comment: Короче, судя по всему, единственный файл, который реально выполняется, — это `~/.zprofile`

Comment: `ssh -t я@хост bash -lic nvm`. вот только я не понял как пробросить `--version`. это нужно доресерчить. но можно в хомы положить скрипт, написать там `nvm --version` и тогда `ssh -t я@хост bash -li q.sh` выводит `0.39.2`

Comment: @nörbörnën у меня прокатило двойное заворачивание в кавычки `"'nvm --version'"` хотя я не понял почему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажи полные пути к программам

Comment: Да вот на версии ubuntu 20.10 все работало и так. Значит проблема в каких то настройках сервера. То есть не хотелось бы менять сами команды запросов в коде их очень много разных. Либо как то можно что то добавить в начало каждой команды чтобы загружался этот login shell?

Comment: Полные пути это хорошо, это надежно